# Angular accessing data after ajax call and render of html

Tags: javascript, angular, css-selectors, rendering

Hi I am trying to figure this out but have yet to do so. All help is much appreciated.

I have an element inside my component:

```
 <div [innerHtml]="reportData" class="widget" #reportDisplayHost></div>
```

Then I have an ajax call that returns a string I bind the return string as such:

```
this.reportData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(response);
```

Once the html data is rendered I want to access some nested elements like so:

```
@ViewChild('reportDisplayHost') reportDisplayHost: ElementRef<any>;
console.log(this.reportDisplayHost.nativeElement.querySelector('chart'));
```

I when I tried to do this I get a **null** but I see the element on the page.

```
<chart exportenabled="1" showalternatehgridcolor="0" basefontsize="11" basefont="Roboto" showborder="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" showshadow="0" use3dlighting="0" legendshadow="0" legendbordercolor="ffffff" showlegend="1" useplotgradientcolor="0" showplotborder="0" showcanvasborder="0" palettecolors="26478d" useroundedges="0" labeldisplay="Rotate" slantlabels="1" yaxismaxvalue="100" yaxisminvalue="0" showvalues="1" yaxisname="Score" xaxisname="Month" caption="Quarterly Score Trends">

<set name="APR-JUN" value="4">&nbsp;</set>
<set name="JUL-SEP" value="7">&nbsp;</set>
<set name="OCT-DEC" value="3">&nbsp;</set>                                                                                                                           
<set name="JAN-MAR" value="3">&nbsp;</set>   
</chart>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you assign `this.reportData`, you want to give Angular a chance to update the DOM before you start querying for child nodes.

You can call [`ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges) to trigger a change detection run before you query for the updated DOM:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

// ...

this.reportData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);

// Update the DOM
this.cd.detectChanges();

// Now we can access the updated DOM
console.log(this.reportDisplayHost.nativeElement.querySelector('chart'));
```

And here's a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arwh4v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks very much I was looking at that and didn't quite understand how it worked.